# My return value appears as NaN and I don’t know why

Tags: javascript, loops

I’m trying to loop through the array and sum all the array values to the `totalValue` variable.

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8],
  validateCred = (arr) => {
    let totalValue;

    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      let number = arr[i] * 2;

      if (number > 9) {
        totalValue += number - 9;
      }
      else {
        totalValue += number;
      }
    }

    return totalValue;
  };

console.log(validateCred(valid1));
```

Comment: This looks like a great spot for a `reduce`. `const validateCred = arr => arr.reduceRight((acc, cur) => acc + (cur > 4.5 ? cur * 2 - 9 : cur * 2));` would be the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give `totalValue` initial value, now it's adding numbers to `undefined` and result is `NaN`

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8]


const validateCred = (arr) => {
let totalValue = 0
   for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       let number = arr[i] *2
       if (number > 9) {
           totalValue += number - 9
       } else {
           totalValue += number
       }
   }
   return totalValue
}

console.log(validateCred(valid1))
```

Also you can use `Array.reduce` method like this

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8]


const totalValue = valid1.reduce((acc, num) => {
  let number = num * 2
  if (number > 9) {
    acc += number - 9
  } else {
    acc += number
  }
  return acc
},0)

console.log(totalValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the value of `totalValue` to 0 before iterating solves the issue by establishing `totalValue` as a number. There are other ways to accomplish this but I believe this to be appropriate.

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8]
//trying to loop through the array and sum all the array values in totalValue variable

const validateCred = (arr) => {
let totalValue = 0;
   for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       let number = arr[i] *2;
       if (number > 9) {
           totalValue += number - 9
       } else {
           totalValue += number
       }
   }
   return totalValue
}

console.log(validateCred(valid1))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your totalValue wasn't initialized.**

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];

const validateCred = (arr) => {
    let totalValue = 0;
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        let number = arr[i] * 2
        if (number > 9) {
            totalValue += number - 9
        } else {
            totalValue += number
        }
    }
    return totalValue
}

console.log(validateCred(valid1))
```